# How can I create filter based on two different fields with OR operator between them in Power View?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, powerview, bism

For example I want to filter my data based on next filter expression:

```
lead_veh_of_interest starts with 'BMW 1'
OR
sale_model starts with 'BMW 1'
```

how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I would create a Dimension-style table eg Car Models, to consolidate the data for Models, then relate to the two existing tables. Then you only need one filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found acceptable solution (thanks for all suggestions - it was very helpful).

First of all I redesigned my model and (how @Mike_Honey suggsts me) created dedicated table with consolidated information I want to filter. Next I connected this new table with existing tables and created **hierarchy** from fields I want to give to the end users for step-wise filtering (previously I split down old fields contained information I want to filter into more granular level). Now it is possible to filter data by any combination of models in any combination of request types (sale, lead, competitor, etc) using **hierarchy**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are these fields both in the same table? If so you could create a calculated column that performs that conditional. Then filter the view on the resulting calculated column.

For example you could create the following calculated column.

Calculated Column: "Starts With BMW 1"

Equation:

```
=IF(OR(Left([lead_veh_of_interest starts], 5) = "BMW 1", Left([sale_Model], 5) = "BMW 1"), 1, 0)
```

Then in the view set the filter so that [Starts With BMW 1] = 1

Comment: Thanx for the tip. Actually I supposed this option as the worst... After all Microsoft presents Power View as self-service BI solution and I would like to solve the problem without modifying the underlying data model. In my case end user may want to filter any other model and any combinations of models... It turns out that I have to create calculated columns for all the combinations of models?